# Lambda expressions in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda, abstract-class

I am trying to build the internet-shop using MVC3. I am using EF and I have one interface to work with my entity context:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IBase, new()
{
    IQueryable<T> Get();
}
```

and one abstract class to work with this interface:

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : 
       IBaseRepository<T> where T : class, IBase, new()
{
    protected abstract ObjectSet<T> EntitySet { get; }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return from obj in EntitySet select obj;
    }
}
```

So I can use this solution to work with different tables in my database(SQL). I can't post images yet. So I will try to describe my database:

**[Product] - [CategoryProduct(ProductID,CategoryID)] - [Category(ShortName)]**

1. Table Product
2. Table Category with field ShortName
3. Table CategoryProduct with fields ProductID,CategoryID to make many-to-many link.

*(We are getting closer to the problem....)*

I have a method, which take "ShortName" from Table "Category"("repository" is the dbcontext only for one table - "Category") And I need to return IEnumerable<> of Products in my view:

```
public ActionResult GetProductInCategory(string shortName)
{
       IEnumerable<Product> = repository.Get()......
        return View();
}
```

So here is the problem: I need to make a query to take product from these 3 tables using lambda, but i can't understand, how to do this.

I can't use linq, because I have direct access only to one table in the whole database.

Sorry for bad eplanation, if you have any questions about architecture to get the whole view, I will try to answer you.

Comment: So you want to return data using a lambda (you'll need LINQ), but you can't get the data because you don't have permission? :S

Comment: I think, it's not that he doesn't have permission, problem is his `IBaseRepository<T>` is constrained to only type, `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming/guessing from your use of the `EntitySet` you're using EntityFramework and you have this structure in you **Entity Classes**

```
Category
+ShortName
+EntityCollection<CategoryProduct> CategoryProduct

CategoryProduct
+Product
```

So you could do this in your linq query:

```
BaseRepository<Category> repository = //get your CATEGORY repository
IEnumerable<Product> = repository.Get().Where(c=> c.ShortName == shortName)
                                       .SelectMany(cp => cp.CategoryProduct)
                                       .Select(p => p.Product).ToList();
```